# How to use environment variable in odoo custom modules

Tags: python, environment-variables, odoo, ubuntu-20.04

I installed odoo in ubuntu 20.04 and I set up environment variables in `/etc/environment`. But odoo is owned by odoo user. So, when I try to call in odoo custom module using `os.environ.get()`, I don't get anything. So, how can I solve that?

Comment: Did you try to restart your system?

Comment: @Paxmees I did.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use the method described here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service

It recommends using `systemctl edit` to create an override file for your service, and then you can add your environment variables to it.

The Odoo service file is visible here:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/debian/odoo.service

Answer (score 0):

You can setup environmental parameters in systemctl service file. this is mine odoo.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Odoo Service Unit

[Service]
Type=simple
User=odoo
Group=odoo
SyslogIdentifier=odoo
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStart=/opt/odoo/odoo-venv/bin/python3 /opt/odoo/odoo/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo.conf
StandardOutput=journal+console
Environment="ODOO_ADDONS_PATH=/opt/odoo/odoo-custom-addons/"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can see the Environment line that in odoo I use as

```
import os
path = os.environ.get("ODOO_ADDONS_PATH")
```